# Using twitterizer to pull data for a specific user

Tags: c#, twitter, twitterizer

I would like to get 
- the numbers of tweets
- the numbers of followers
- the numbers of retweet (RT or Retweet)
- the numbers of mentioning (@).

Could you help me? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It's all in the documentation :)

http://www.twitterizer.net/documentation/html/T_Twitterizer_TwitterUser.htm

Comment: Exactly right. Between the docs, the forums, and the example applications you should be able to find the answers to questions like this easily.

Comment: Nice @Ricky, but the only thing I am not finding by now is the email address.

Comment: The Twitter API does not, nor will it ever, expose the user's email address. Otherwise, the API would be spammer's dream.

Comment: Oh, seems the project has been closed down https://github.com/Twitterizer/Twitterizer

Comment: 404 Page not found :(